# StyleID Issue in JSP, Place where it is assigned

Tags: jsp

In my JSP I am trying to add a field with a check box option. I am modifying the existing code.

Existing Code is,

```
<tr>
    <td class="right">
        <signifo:label key="vendor.title"/> Enabled
    </td>
    <td class="left">
        <html:checkbox property="vendorEnabled" styleId="vendorchkbx" onclick="isVendorEnabled(this);"/>
        <html:hidden property="vendorEnabled" value="false"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Modified one is

```
<tr>
    <td class="right">
        <signifo:label key="duplicatecheck.title"/> Enabled
    </td>
    <td class="left">
        <html:checkbox property="duplicateCheckEnabled" styleId="duplicatechkbx"/>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

In the modified one,`styleId` is `duplicatechkbx`, please tell me where this might be assigned as check box?

In any Javascript or CSS?

I have no idea.. please somebody help.

Regards.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "where this might be assigned as check box"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.No no i got it thanks. Actually I thought that duplicatechkbx is actual checkbox definition. Later on i found that is only the actual place where it is assigned to use further.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. sorry for confusing you with my question. It is mapped with the database object which will update the database and the data from database displayed, when ever the page is called.